# CSS Browser hack for ≥ IE10, Index was outside the bounds of the array

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc, internet-explorer, microsoft-edge

Tried to add this browser selector hack for  [Internet Explorer/Edge ≥ 10](http://browserhacks.com/#hack-f1070533535a12744a0381a75087a915)

```
_:-ms-input-placeholder, :root input[type="range"] {
    display: block;  
}
```

I use `@Styles.Render("~/content/myCssBundle")` to render my CSS.
**But when I include the hack from above in one of my css files, I get:**
Index was outside the bounds of the array.

[image]

The bundler seems to have a problem with this css hack, very strange!

Answer (score 0):

While the above selector leads to the above issue, 
the following selector plays well with the ASP.NET CSS bundling/rendering system:

**>= IE10**

```
@media screen and (-ms-high-contrast: active), (-ms-high-contrast: none) {    
   .YourSelector{

   }
}
```

**Microsoft Edge Browser 12+ (All)**

```
@supports (-ms-ime-align:auto) {
  .selector { property:value; } 
}
```